# debugging cross validation code

Tags: r, machine-learning

I am trying to do a 10-fold cross validation by hand. My data set is called `spam`.

My code is as follows:

```
n <- nrow(spam) #4600 rows in spam data set
ncp <- length(spam.rpart2$cptable[,"CP"]) #20 CP values
group <- rep(1:10,ceiling(n/10))[1:n] #fill 4600 values with 1 to 10
permid <- sample(1:n) #permute numbers
cvtable <- matrix(NA, n, ncp) 

for(j in 1:20) {
    for(i in 1:10) {
    trainingset <- permid[group!=i]
    testset <- permid[group==i]
    spam.rpart.test <- rpart(spam ~ ., 
                             method = "class",
                             cp = spam.rpart2$cptable[j,"CP"],
                             data = spam[trainingset,])
    cvtable[testset,j] <- predict(spam.rpart.test, 
                                  data=spam[testset,])[,1]
#incorrect dimensions!
     }
}
```

However, I am having trouble in the third to last line. The predicted values should only be predicting 460 values, but it is giving me 4160 values, and so the for loop code isn't running. I get the following error:

```
Error in cvtable[testset, j] <- predict(spam.rpart.test, data = spam[testset,  : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Comment: Is there a reason you prefer to do this by hand rather than using already existing (well implemented) CV options through packages like `caret`?

Comment: i am trying to practice coding!

Comment: is there a problem with the way i have used the rpart() function? i've spent hours debugging and cant seem to figure this out... thank you!!

Comment: It appears you are passing the exact same sample each time through the loop. Was this desired?

Comment: I've noticed that 6/9 of your questions have answers and not one is checked as correct.  It may help the response rate if you marked some of those as correct if they indeed suited your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You want to specify `newdata` to predict, per `?predict.rpart`, otherwise you are getting predictions for the training set saved in the model. The corrected code may look like:

```
cvtable[testset, j] <- predict(spam.rpart.test, 
                              newdata=spam[testset,])[,1]
```

The mystery is that the error message should flag 4140 replacement entries, not 4160.